# Error when installing phalconEye

Tags: phalcon, phalconeye

I'm trying to install PhalconEye, and when I submit the infos about the database, the installation stops proceeding, and the error below is displayed

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your database already have a table with another structure. Check your database.

Comment: Yes, I figure out that I have already the table users in my previous database